# How many spanning trees (undirected) are there with exactly k leaf?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

It occurred to me that in order to find how many of those are there, for every $k$ it's a bit different way of thinking, for example:

for $k$ = 3 the answer is:

$\binom{n}{3}(n-3)\frac{(n-2)!}{2!}$

for $k$ = 4 it gets a bit more complicated:

$\binom{n}{4}[(n-4)\frac{(n-2)!}{3!}+\binom{n-4}{2}\frac{(n-2)!}{2!*2!}]$
 (which, to be honest, i'm not sure why)

of course I can make it a simple cayley's problem:

How many words with $n-2$ letters from $n$ possible letters are there, when there are exactly $k$ letters that are not in the word? but that won't give me the answer i wrote above.

Comment: Spannomg trees of what, the complete graph on $n$ nodes?

Comment: with $n$ nodes, sorry, I forgot to mention that. complete? No, i'm talking about regular trees

Comment: "Spanning tree" is defined relative to a graph, not a set of nodes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree So you are talking about the spanning tress of the complete graph on $n$ nodes.

Comment: yes. correct. sorry again.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you want, as you mention in comments is given by the number of lists of length $n-2$ which have exactly $n-k$ different letters inside the list. This is because every vertex in the tree appears in its code expect for the leaves, the leaves never appear.We shall first select the $n-k$ etters we want to appear in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways. Then we shall partition the spots in which the letters appear in the code in $n-k$ parts in ${n-2 \brace {n-k}}$ ways, and finally we shall multiply by $(n-k)!$ to select which part of the partition gets which number.

So the final answer is $\binom{n}{k}{{n-2}\brace{n-k}}(n-k)!$

Where $n\brace k$ is the [stirling number of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not right.
Look at the question I posted, and the answers that are right for  $k = 3$ and $k = 4$...

Comment: It is right! where did you get your answers from?

Comment: think about that: let's take $k=5$ for instance, if your'e saying it's $(n-5)^{n-2}$ it means that there are some letters that won't necessarily will be on the list, meaning they will be leafs, and you already took care of that.
for example: $n = 10$, we choose the leafs to be: $1,2,3,4,5$ but the Prüfer Code we decide to create is $66666666$ - now look what happened - we created a graph which has more than 5 leafs.

Comment: Oh, of course! we want all of the letters we selected to appear, let me make some modifications.

Comment: Thanks, I'm ashamed to admit that i don't know what's the meaning of stirling numbers

Answer (score 0):

I found it.
Using the Inclusion - Exclusion principle,

$W(0) = n-k^{n-2}$

$W(r) = \binom{n-k}{r}(n-k-r)^{n-2}$

So, we choose which letters won't appear: $\binom{n}{k}$
and then apply the principle.
the answer comes out:

**$\binom{n}{k}\sum_{r=0}^{n-k}(-1)^{r}\binom{n-k}{r}(n-k-r)^{n-2}$**